# C# reflection dictionary

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, dictionary

say I have this code:

```
Dictionary<String, String> myDictionary = new Dictionary<String, String>();
Type[] arguments = myDictionary.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
```

In my program, myDictionary it's of unknown types (it's an object returned from a deserialized XML), but for the purpose of this question, they are string. I want to create something like this:

```
Dictionary<arguments[0],arguments[1]> mySecondDictionary = new Dictionary<arguments[0],arguments[1]>();
```

Obviously, it doesn't work.
I searched on MSDN, and I saw they are using the Activator class, but I don't get it.
Maybe somebody more advanced, could help me a little.

Comment: Please give your question a meaningful title. Don't just list tags. This makes no sense and doesn't attract users to look into and try to help you.

Comment: Just a note on your recently removed question.  [Everything has been invented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Holland_Duell)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the activator class like you mentioned in order to create objects from given types. The [MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) method allows you to specify an array of Types as the parameters for generic objects, which is what you were trying to simulate.

```
Dictionary<String, String> myDictionary = new Dictionary<String, String>();
Type[] arguments = myDictionary.GetType().GetGenericArguments();

Type dictToCreate = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(arguments);
var mySecondDictionary = Activator.CreateInstance(dictToCreate);
```

The code above is essentially pointless as you know that the dictionary is `String,String` beforehand but assuming you have a way of detecting the required types elsewhere during runtime, you can use the last two lines to instantiate a dictionary of that type.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with this approach.
I will try my best to explain it.
I wrote a program which first serializes a class into XML, then deserializes it back. 
Basically, the class it's a generic one, and it contains a List(the same type with the class).
So, the type of the class could be anything, starting from simple types, like string, int, etc to more complex classes, like for example a book class, or a person. After using the XmlSerializer.Deserialize method, and getting the object, I should use Reflection to reconstruct back the object, and access the list. And I can't do it that way.
So, if I have something like:

```
Type classToCreate = typeof(classToBeSerialized<>).MakeGenericType(arguments);
var reconstructedClass = Activator.CreateInstance(classToCreate);
```

where classToBeSerialized it's the supposed class(which has the list which I have spoken of), and returnedObject it's the object returned from XmlSerializer.Deserialize, I want to access the list like this:

```
 ((reconstructedClass)returnedObject).lista
```

Basically, I'm using reflection to cast the object to it's source.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I just needed something similar, and decided to show it, (you know for google).

this is basicly a rewrite of the answer by @user2536272

```
public object ConstructDictionary(Type KeyType, Type ValueType)
{
    Type[] TemplateTypes = new Type[]{KeyType, ValueType};
    Type DictionaryType = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(TemplateTypes);

    return Activator.CreateInstance(DictionaryType);
}

public void AddToDictionary(object DictionaryObject, object KeyObject, object ValueObject )
{
    Type DictionaryType = DictionaryObject.GetType();

    if (!(DictionaryType .IsGenericType && DictionaryType .GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>)))
        throw new Exception("sorry object is not a dictionary");

    Type[] TemplateTypes = DictionaryType.GetGenericArguments();
    var add = DictionaryType.GetMethod("Add", new[] { TemplateTypes[0], TemplateTypes[1] });
    add.Invoke(DictionaryObject, new object[] { KeyObject, ValueObject });
}
```

Comment: Been looking for this solution for a long time.  Works like a charm.